# ipad simulator error after distribution

Tags: xcode, ipad, distribution

I developed a test app and I tried to use into the simulator.. all works fine!
After, following the document "iPhone_developer_program_user_guide" I made the distribution version of my app (and xcode built it without problems).
After this, I couldn't try the distribution 'cause I don't have iPad, but when I selected the debug type and relaunched to the simulator, the simulator starts, become all black and xcode give this error:
[error http://www.ghiboz.info/shots/ed342dc8.png](http://www.ghiboz.info/shots/ed342dc8.png)
I sent the .app and the .mobileprovision to my mate that have the iPad (configured with the udid) and retrieve an unknown error (0xE8008001)...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, simply remove the app from the simulator.. xcode is not able to do this....